# pass lambda expression as callback to an extension method and pass parameter to it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to understand the concept of lambda expression,extension method,Linq and IEnumerable interface. You can guess that i am farely new to c sharp.Here i've come up with a problem which will incorporate all the above mentioned concepts . Here i have a list which contain three object.I want to change the name property of a Students object in a specified index .I wrote an extension method which accept a callback function.Callback function accepts an integer index and a new Name string. It should change the name property and return the object .But my code failed to do so as i am not sure how to pass parameter to Func callback in extension method.I am in need of some assistant to understand the problem and fix errors from my code ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Students> students = new List<Students>();

        students.Add(new Students(111443, "sakib"));
        students.Add(new Students(111445, "zami"));
        students.Add(new Students(111444, "habib"));

        var student = students.First();

        var changed1 = students.Change((int num,string newname) => { return students[num].s_name = newname;});


    }
}

public class Students
{
    public int s_id;

    public string s_name;

    public Students(int id, string name)
    {
        this.s_id = id;

        this.s_name = name;
    }
}

public static class LinqHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Change<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<int,string,T> callback)
    {
        var myList = new List<Students>();

        myList.Add(callback(1,"zami")); // i was passing parameter here which is not so helpful i guess !

        return myList;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Func < int, string, T > denotes a function that accepts an integer and string as inputs and T as the return type. The anonymous function you have used has a return type of "string":

```
var changed1 = students.Change((int num,string newname) => { return students[num].s_name = newname;});
```

You should return the student instance from the function to make it work. Try replacing the above code with the following:

```
var changed1 = students.Change((int index, string newname) => 
                                         {
                                             var studentObj = students[index];
                                             studentObj.s_name = newname;
                                             return studentObj;
                                         });
```

To allow the LinqHelper to accept the index and argument, use the following:

```
public static class LinqHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Change<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<int, string, T> callback, int index, string argument)
    {
        var myList = new List<T>();

        myList.Add(callback(index, argument)); // i was passing parameter here which is not so helpful i guess !

        return myList;

    }
}
```

And then, you could invoke the method as follows:

```
var changed1 = students.Change((int index, string newname) => 
                                         {
                                             var studentObj = students[index];
                                             studentObj.s_name = newname;
                                             return studentObj;
                                         }, 
                                         1, 
                                         "zami");
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created the lambda that evaluated to `Func<int, string, T>`. Your call to Change extension should look like:

```
var changed1 = students.Change((num, newnam) => {  
                            students[num].s_name = newnam; 
                            return students[num];
                         });
```

(you should return `T` as `Func` requires).

Comment: I have passed parameters to callback from inside extension method
Like this myList.Add(callback(1,"zami")) .
But i want this to be dynamic. If i pass parameters from within extension method  to callback then for each index i have to make changes inside extension method.
How to avoid this issue?

Comment: you should add the two new parameters to your Change method to pass to callback (like Change(1, "zami", () => {...} )  (but it'll be 'fuzzy logic' IMO.) You can also create a Func<T> and pass the lambda: () => { students[1] = "zami"; return students[1]; } - depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: thnx for the help